# How to expand variadic arguments in a macro?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, c99, variadic-macros

I want to essentially have a macro shortener.

The macro, `FOO(A,B,C)` should expand to
`defined(_FOO_A) || defined(_FOO_B) || defined(_FOO_C)`.

Is that possible in GCC using variadic macro arguments and not actually writing 3 functions (`FOO(A)`, `FOO(A,B)`, `FOO(A,B,C)`) ?

Comment: Identifiers that start with two underscores or with one underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the language implementation.

Comment: Seems very similar to http://efesx.com/2010/08/31/overloading-macros/ and http://efesx.com/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/ You are most welcome to have a look.

Comment: Normally, I'd say write a loop that goes through the arguments and checks each defined... however, if defined is used in the context of a preprocessor directive, that's a no-go.

Comment: The code you provided is an example of what you want in the general case or you need exactly that macro?

Comment: @CarlNorum: I agree. I just provided it as an example and to distinguish between FOO and _FOO.

Comment: @effeffe: I need that exact macro, with FOO substituted with another literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have a macro to expand to something that contains the `defined` keyword:

> If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement
>   process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the
>   two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So you can't do it with `defined`. If you are willing to relax that constraint by just testing the value of `FOO_A_`, `FOO_B_`, ... there are ways to do this by using [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr). E.g just doing a logical or of a list of variables would be

```
#if P99_ORS(A, B, C)
...
#endif
```

where the `P99_ORS` expression expands to

```
((((A) || (B))) || (C))
```

and is then evaluated for `#if` the expression.

There would also be ways to expand that first into a token list of your liking, if you want to do some macro programming

```
#define P00_NAME_X(NAME, X, I) P99_PASTE2(NAME, X)
#define CONDITION(NAME, ...) P99_ORS(P99_FOR(FOO_, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_SEQ, P00_NAME_X, __VA_ARGS__))
```

such that

```
CONDITION(A, B, C, toto);
```

would expand to

```
((((((FOO_A) || (FOO_B))) || (FOO_C))) || (FOO_toto));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(A, B, C) (FOO_X(A) || FOO_X(B) || FOO_X(C))
#define FOO_X(x) defined(_FOO_##x)

// just to print it
#define QUOTE(...) QUOTE_AUX(__VA_ARGS__)
#define QUOTE_AUX(...) #__VA_ARGS__

int main(void)
{
    puts(QUOTE(FOO(a, b, c)));
}
```

**EDIT**: actually this results **undefined behavior**, in all C standards.

Comment: Unfortunately this is forbidden by the standard. `define` is not allowed to appear in a macro expansion.